# Label Content and progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I create windows form application and add progress bar for show the progress of loaded files,and label above progress bar to show the path of each file but sum path very long and appear in line but my width form small for that some of path not appear all,I see more than one solution in stack overflow and google but didn't useful as make Auto size false ,dock fill,and change size.I want method dynamic change of the length of path.

Comment: i used  label3.Text = string.Format("[ {0} of {1} ] Processing {2}", pdfnum, allfilesinfolder, path); but don't see the content of label at the finish progress i see the last content label ????????

Comment: That's happening because you're performing a long running process on the main thread, please see my answer for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire path to appear (e.g. wrap) you will need to set the `Height` of the `Label` to something, let's say `50`. So it might be something like a `Label` with a `Height` of `50` and a `Width` of `300` and then a `ProgressBar` beneath that.

Further, it appears your problem is that you're performing a long running operation on the main thread. That's why the `Label` isn't refreshing. You need to leverage a `BackgroundWorker`. So, add a class variable for it:

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

and then in the `ctor` do this:

```
_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
_worker.DoWork += DoBackgroundWork;
_worker.ProgressChanged += ReportProgress;
```

and then for those handlers:

```
private void DoBackgroundWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do the work you're doing in here -but add the below line when you want
    // to update the text of your label
    _worker.ReportProgress(1, "Your label text here");
}

private void ReportProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.label.Text = e.UserState as string;
}
```

---

One final thing you might want to consider, and that is cutting off the string to what is **close** to the length of your label rather than trying to make it wrap. Below is a set of methods that prove one possible solution for that.

**One thing to note** is that the cutoff procedure leverages a bin search, so it's not ***incredibly*** accurate. What do I mean by that? Well, let's say you have a string that's 150 characters long (like the one in the example below) and the first time it cuts it in half and measures the string. If that width is less than the maximum width (e.g. the width of the `Label`) it's simply going to return that string. That works, but it's possible that there was space left on the length of the label and less characters could have been truncated.

To make this more accurate you would have to make more passes, and IMO, that's just not important enough to make enumerable passes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] chars = new string[]
    {
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filePath = BuildString(150);
        var g = this.label1.CreateGraphics();
        var size = g.MeasureString(filePath, this.Font);
        var oneCharacterLen = (size.Width / (float)filePath.Length);
        if (size.Width > ((float)this.label1.Width - (oneCharacterLen * 3f)))
        {
            this.label1.Text = CutoffStringBinSearch(g, string.Format("{0}", filePath), 0, this.label1.Width);
        }
    }

    private string CutoffStringBinSearch(Graphics g, string s, int startIndex, int maxWidth)
    {
        var midPoint = (s.Length - startIndex) / 2;
        var subString = string.Format("{0}...", s.Substring(startIndex, midPoint));

        var len = g.MeasureString(subString, this.Font);
        if (len.Width > (float)maxWidth) { return CutoffStringBinSearch(g, s.Substring(startIndex, midPoint), 0, maxWidth); }

        return subString;
    }

    private string BuildString(int len)
    {
        string[] s = new string[len];
        var random = new Random(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            s[i] = chars[random.Next(0, chars.Length - 1)];
        }
        return string.Join("", s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand background good,I made label and progress bar and label refresh with progress bar but the text of label change very fast it is correct or not ?????????

Comment: @Dina, I'm sure it does appear fast, but that's just because the operation you're performing on the file isn't that big. It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
```

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BackgroundWorkerSimple
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

```
    private void startAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    // This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use labelX.Refresh().

```
label1.Text = "First text";
Thread.Sleep(1500); //*This line is only for testing purpose as the change is pretty quick*. 
progressBar1.Value = 50;
label1.Refresh();
label1.Text = "Second text";
Thread.Sleep(1500); //*This line is only for testing purpose as the change is pretty quick*. 
label1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Nithya, you just posted on a question from 2013 with a very wrong answer. Calling `Sleep()` from the main UI thread is almost never the correct approach...

Comment: @Idle_Mind , I know that Thread.Sleep won't come in production level. It is impossible to add it. But I have mentioned it because if you test without the sleep, the changes in the progress bar is pretty quick and not visible. That is for testing purpose. I have changed my comment. My intent was for the Refresh() method. Test this code first and then downvote.

Comment: Your code implies that simply calling `Refresh()` will cause the UI to update.  This is definitely not the case if you have some kind of  "work" running in the main UI thread (such as if this code was in a Button click handler). Someone will look at your example code and try to replace that call to `Sleep()` in your example with something else. A better example might use async/await?